# Hi , I have error during examinig simple publisher & subscriber (c++)

Tags: c++, catkin, roscore, rosrun, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use groovy distribution & catkin
first , I wrote the simple publisher & subscriber example that in beginner tutorials

then I tried to examine it following the following steps

- typing command `roscore` in catkin
- I made sure I have sourced my
  workspace's `setup.sh` file after
  calling `catkin_make` but before

trying to  my  applications:

```
>  In your catkin workspace
>      cd ~/catkin_ws    
>      source ./devel/setup.bash
```

- run the node talker using command

> `rosrun beginner_tutorials talker`

but, when I typed command `rosrun beginner_tutorials talker`
I recevied in output:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/eman/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
```

even though the node talker exists in the src of begibnner_turorials package
& my **CMakeLists.txt** file looks like that:-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy  std_msgs)

## Declare ROS messages and services ##

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(  FILES  Message1.msg Message2.msg )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(FILES Service1.srv Service2.srv )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages( DEPENDENCIES std_msgs )

## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES beginner_tutorials
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(beginner_tutorials
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/beginner_tutorials.cpp
# )

## Declare a cpp executable
# add_executable(beginner_tutorials_node src/beginner_tutorials_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(beginner_tutorials_node beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(beginner_tutorials_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# ries(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

    

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

any help,please

I wonder what is the reason for having that error??

- I made sure that Ros can find my
  package ( beginner_tutorials ) using command
  `rospack find beginner_tutorials` & it
  returns its path

> ```
> /home/eman/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
> ```

so, that mean ros can see & find my package .

---

- I also made sure that the code of 2
  nodes talker & listener exits in the
  src folder of my package

---

- , but when I tried to build the code
  using command `catkin_make`

---

1. typing 1st command `cd ~/catkin_ws/src`
2. then typing 2nd command `catkin_make`

I had that error :-

```
> The specified base path
> "/home/eman/catkin_ws/src" contains a
> CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must
> be invoked in the root of workspace
```

---

I tried also

- 1-typing 1st command `cd ~/catkin_ws`
- 2- then typing 2nd command   `catkin_make`

but,  I had error

```
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/cmake/roscppConfig.cmake:130 (message):
  Project 'beginner_tutorials' tried to find library 'pthread'.  The library
  is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'roscpp'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its
  code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package)
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

what should I do ??
should I rebuild the catkin_ws & the package???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105961/hi-,-i-have-error-during-examinig-simple-publisher-&-subscriber-(c++)/) by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2013-11-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-11-30**:
Do you see build output from your node when executing catkin_make? In your src folder there only should be the source code of your node, because catkin does out-of-source-builds.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-11-30**:
@BennyRe
firstly, thank you very much for your help & your note.God bless you amen After I had executed catkin_make , I had the following output eman@eman-K52F:~$ catkin_make Base path: /home/eman Source space: /home/eman/src Build space: /home/eman/build Devel space: /home/eman/devel Install space: /home/eman/install #### #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/eman/build" #### #### #### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/eman/build" #### eman@eman-K52F:~$ you mean by src folder ( the src folder of the package beginner_tutorials ) ??? am I right ?

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-11-30**:
@BennyRe

I made sure that the code of  2 nodes ( talker & listener ) are found in the src folder of the package beginner_tutorials
,but I still having the same error
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/eman/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
I am really sorry for disturbance , but I have the same error & I don't know what to do

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-12-01**:
The output of catkin_make looks strange. There should be some output of your package. Did you create the package and your workspace correctly. Did you follow the catkin workspace tutorial? I mean, because your src/build/devel folders are located directly in your home folder.

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-12-02**:
It'll probably help if you can edit your question to include your CMakeLists.txt file.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-02**:
@BennyRe
Thank you very much for your response . God bless you amen.
I am sorry for being late to reply , but I had  a problem with my internet connection .

I suppose I created the package and my workspace correctly  .
&yes,  I followed  the catkin workspace tutorial and every thing was going well similar to the outputs of the tutorial at that time .

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-02**:
@BennyRe
The output may look strange because I didn't type the command " cd ~/catkin_ws/ before typing command " catkin_make " I am not sure about that ,but may be that was the reason. That output after 1-typing command " cd ~/catkin_ws/ " 2- then typing command " catkin_make " eman@eman-K52F:~/catkin_ws/src$ cd ~/catkin_ws/ eman@eman-K52F:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make Base path: /home/eman/catkin_ws Source space: /home/eman/catkin_ws/src Build space: /home/eman/catkin_ws/build Devel space: /home/eman/catkin_ws/devel Install space: /home/eman/catkin_ws/install #### #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/eman/catkin_ws/build" #### -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/eman/catkin_ws/devel -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/eman/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy -- This workspace overlays: /home/eman/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy -- Using Debian Python package layout -- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON -- Call enable_testing()

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-02**:
@BennyRe
but there is error at the end of the output -- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials' -- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials) CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/cmake/roscppConfig.cmake:130 (message): Project 'beginner_tutorials' tried to find library 'pthread'. The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly. Did you compile project 'roscpp'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its code is included? Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package) beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package) -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1 Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-02**:
@lindzey
Thank you for your response & your note . God bless you amen . Ok , I will edit my question to include my CMakeLists.txt file

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-12-02**:
Please put the content of your CMakeLists.txt into a code environment. It's very hard to read at the moment.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-12-03**:
Thanks joq. Don't have enough karma to edit.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-12-03**:
You should always be able to edit your own question. If that does not work, send an admin message.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-03**:
@BennyRe
Sorry  I tried to edit it ,but it didn't work
& Thanks alot for your response . I really appreciate that . God bless you amen.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-03**:
@joq
Thanks alot for your edit , I really appreciate that . God bless you amen
& Thanks for your note , I will take care about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on your most recent update:

> typing 1st command cd ~/catkin_ws/src

> then typing 2nd command catkin_make

Your problem is that you need to invoke catkin_make in `catkin_ws` not `catkin_ws/src`.

However, this is a different mistake than some of the other error messages you've posted would indicate.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-04**:
Thanks alot  .God bless you amen
but when I tried
1-typing 1st command cd ~/catkin_ws
2- then typing 2nd command catkin_make
I had error
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/cmake/roscppConfig.cmake:130 (message):
Project 'beginner_tutorials' tried to find library 'pthread'.  The library
is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
'roscpp'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its
code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package)
beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-12-04**:
please edit your original question to include this information, formatted nicely.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thanks for your help . God bless you amen
Ok , I will edit my original question to include this information, formatted nicely.